# Changing absolute element position with getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, getboundingclientrect

I created a small reproduction of my code with which i have an issue. I wanted to create a functionality of small square element `(.box)` sliding to the center of selected answer. Currently its sliding wrong as its going completely different direction than it should. I assume i would need to use commented line  `// const boxRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();` and play with its position but tried several times without success.

The important thing is that the first slide must start from `.box` initial position defined in css. Then it should just change its position between selected answers.

```js
const { useRef } = React;

const ANSWERS = ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"];

const App = () => {
   const boxRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSelectAnswer = (answer) => {
    const selectedAnswerElement = document.querySelector(
      `[data-answer="${answer}"]`
    );
    const box = boxRef.current;
    const answersContainer = document.querySelector(".answers");

    if (selectedAnswerElement && box && answersContainer) {
      const selectedAnswerRect = selectedAnswerElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const containerRect = answersContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
      // const boxRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();

      const offsetX =
        selectedAnswerRect.left -
        containerRect.left +
        selectedAnswerRect.width / 2;

      const offsetY =
        selectedAnswerRect.top -
        containerRect.top +
        selectedAnswerRect.height / 2;

      box.style.transform = `translate(${offsetX}px, ${offsetY}px)`;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="answers">
      {ANSWERS.map((answer) => (
        <button
          key={answer}
          data-answer={answer}
          onClick={() => handleSelectAnswer(answer)}
        >
          {answer}
        </button>
      ))}

      <div className="box" ref={boxRef} />
    </div>
  
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.answers {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 270px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.answers button {
  height: 150px;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the box on top of an answer by moving its center to "on top of the answer's center", e.g.

```js
const { width: bw, height: bh } = box.getBoundingClientRect();
const { top, left, width, height } = selectedAnswerElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const newBoxTop = top + height/2 - bh/2 + window.scrollY);
const newBoxLeft = left + width/2 - bw/2 + window.scrollX);
```

(Remembering to take scroll x/y into account)

And while you can compute the position using JS, you probably want to use CSS to handle the rest by setting CSS variables rather than messing with `element.style` properties directly, because you want your CSS to live in your CSS files, not in your CSS *and* your JS. Define your CSS rules in terms of CSS variables, and then make JS update those variables only:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React;

const ANSWERS = ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"];

const App = () => {
  const boxRef = useRef(null);
  
  // Switch the box to use absolute positioning once it's on the page.
  useEffect(() => {
    const box = boxRef.current;
    const { top, left } = box.getBoundingClientRect();
    box.classList.add(`ready`);
    box.style.setProperty(`--top`, top);
    box.style.setProperty(`--left`, left);
  }, []);

  // then move its center to a clicked answer's box's center
  const handleSelectAnswer = (answer) => {
    const box = boxRef.current;
    const { width: bw, height: bh } = box.getBoundingClientRect();

    const selectedAnswerElement = document.querySelector(`.answers [data-answer="${answer}"]`);
    const { top, left, width, height } = selectedAnswerElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    // move the centers, remembering to take h/vscroll into account:
    box.style.setProperty(`--top`, top + height/2 - bh/2 + window.scrollY);
    box.style.setProperty(`--left`, left + width/2 - bw/2 + window.scrollX);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="answers">
        {ANSWERS.map((answer) => (
          <button key={answer} data-answer={answer} onClick={() => handleSelectAnswer(answer)}>
            {answer}
          </button>
        ))}
        <div className="box" ref={boxRef} />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.answers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 270px);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a a"
    "a a"
    "box box";
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}

.answers button {
  height: 150px;
}

.box {
  grid-area: box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box.ready {
  --top: 0;
  --left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--top) * 1px);
  left: calc(var(--left) * 1px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Its hard to apply this solution to the styles i provided in the snippet

Comment: That's fair, let me update it to use the same ones, but I'll be updating your grid so that the button isn't violating the whole _point_ of grid =)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed default left, right and bottom css from your box elements so it will not cause any issue in dynamic position property in js and Also I have used state to store the x and y position of box element.
Please check updated below code.

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect } = React;

const ANSWERS = ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"];

const App = () => {
   const boxRef = useRef(null);
     const [boxPosition, setBoxPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });


  const handleSelectAnswer = (answer) => {
    const selectedAnswerElement = document.querySelector(
      `[data-answer="${answer}"]`
    );
    const box = boxRef.current;
    const answersContainer = document.querySelector(".answers");

    if (selectedAnswerElement && box && answersContainer) {
      const selectedAnswerRect = selectedAnswerElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const containerRect = answersContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
      const boxRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();

       const offsetX = selectedAnswerRect.left - containerRect.left;
      const offsetY = selectedAnswerRect.top - containerRect.top;

      const boxOffsetX = offsetX + selectedAnswerRect.width / 2 - boxRect.width / 2;
      const boxOffsetY = offsetY + selectedAnswerRect.height / 2 - boxRect.height / 2;
      
      setBoxPosition({ x: boxOffsetX, y: boxOffsetY });
    }
  };
  
   useEffect(() => {
    handleSelectAnswer(ANSWERS[0])
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="answers">
      {ANSWERS.map((answer) => (
        <button
          key={answer}
          data-answer={answer}
          onClick={() => handleSelectAnswer(answer)}
        >
          {answer}
        </button>
      ))}

      <div className="box" ref={boxRef} style={{ transform: `translate(${boxPosition.x}px, ${boxPosition.y}px)` }} />
    </div>
  
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.answers {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 270px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.answers button {
  height: 150px;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Unfortunately the .box element must start its first slide towards selected answer  from the initial position (below answers container) defined in css :/

Comment: So you mean initial the .box element should be on the bottom of answer container and then on load it should move to answer 1 (considering that answer 1 is selected answer) like it was working in your snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

Extending to your approach I have just added one more reference variable to store the initial coordinates of the box. And now I am calculating the transform offsets taking those initial coordinates as reference.

Apart from the functionality you mention I have also added that if the user clicks on the already selected answer, then the box slides back to its initial position.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const ANSWERS = ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"]

const App = () => {
  const boxRef = useRef(null)
  const initialPositionOfBoxRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const rect = boxRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    const answersContainer = document.querySelector(".answers")
    const containerRect = answersContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
    initialPositionOfBoxRef.current = { x: Math.floor(rect.left - containerRect.left + rect.width / 2), y: Math.floor(rect.top - containerRect.top + rect.height / 2) }
  }, [])

  const handleSelectAnswer = (answer) => {
    const selectedAnswerElement = document.querySelector(
      `[data-answer="${answer}"]`
    )
    const box = boxRef.current
    const answersContainer = document.querySelector(".answers")

    if (selectedAnswerElement && box && answersContainer) {
      const selectedAnswerRect = selectedAnswerElement.getBoundingClientRect()
const containerRect = answersContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
      const boxRect = box.getBoundingClientRect()

      const selectedAnswerRectCenter = { x: Math.floor(selectedAnswerRect.left - containerRect.left + selectedAnswerRect.width / 2), y: Math.floor(selectedAnswerRect.top - containerRect.top + selectedAnswerRect.height / 2) }
        const boxRectCenter = { x: Math.floor(boxRect.left - containerRect.left + boxRect.width / 2), y: Math.floor(boxRect.top - containerRect.top + boxRect.height / 2) }

      const offsetX = selectedAnswerRectCenter.x - initialPositionOfBoxRef.current.x
        const offsetY = selectedAnswerRectCenter.y - initialPositionOfBoxRef.current.y

      if (selectedAnswerRectCenter.x === boxRectCenter.x && selectedAnswerRectCenter.y === boxRectCenter.y) {
        box.style.transform = `translate(${0}px, ${0}px)`
      } else {
        box.style.transform = `translate(${offsetX}px, ${offsetY}px)`
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="answers">
      {ANSWERS.map((answer) => (
        <button
          key={answer}
          data-answer={answer}
          onClick={() => handleSelectAnswer(answer)}
        >
          {answer}
        </button>
      ))}

      <div className="box" ref={boxRef} />
    </div>

  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.answers {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 270px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

.answers button {
  height: 150px;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Works only for the first row of answers, moving to second row is buggy

Comment: This issue originated as a result of coordinated calculation w.r.t viewport. So, I resolved this issue (By calculating coordinated w.r.t answers container) and edited the above answer as per the changes.